# How can i remove (') from a string result, in order to use in subproduct i need not to have (')

Tags: python-3.x

Im creating a name based on different inputs by the user, it constructs this way:

```
Result = str('Blue' + shoetype.result + '5')
Result = 'Bluesandal5'
```

now i need to use 'Bluesandal5' in another operation, but i need it with out the ('), just Bluesandal5

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `'` characters are there for the specific purpose of telling you that it's a string. They disappear when you actually *use* the string for something. Example, using my python console:

```py
>>> Result = "Bluesandal5"
>>> Result
'Bluesandal5'
>>> print(Result)
Bluesandal5
```

As you can see, the quotes disappear when it's used in a `print()` statement. This also holds true for any other operation (e.g. string slicing) - they don't count as part of the string itself.

Comment: Thats what I though, but its not using it like that, this is the error while trying to use this result in a SQL query exectution. DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'Bluesandal5': ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. Its taking it with the (')

Comment: I think that operation is failing for a different reason, and the error output just happens to be using `'` to tell you the particular name that was connected to the failure (because otherwise it might be ambiguous what that was). Take another look at the statement itself to see if it's invalid or not.

Comment: When i manually insert just Bluesandal5 it works, when it uses my construtcted string, it fails

Comment: when you execute 'Bluesandal5' it pops 'Bluesandal5', if you execute just Bluesandal5, then it displays the sql query, i need 'Bluesandal5' to point to Bluesandal5 which contains the SQL query needed.

Comment: How exactly are you inserting it into the query?

Comment: I have a query contained in Bluesandal5 and others, then when the user depending on the options it selects, it constructs  Result = str('Blue' + shoetype.result + '5'), and depending on the selection it calls the query with that name that name and run it in the sql. well thats my code idea.